# Github Mac App How To Change Default Storage Directory

Tags: github, github-for-mac

In the github mac app i am trying to change the default directory of one of my repo's. In the settings screen I only see a place to change the remote repo. 
[image]

Where do I need to go to change the default location? Sorry if it is very obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some trial and error I figured out how to change the location after you have set it up. Apparently it is as easy as just moving the folder that contains the .git. So for example I just moved the website folder into a new directory and the GitHub app was able to track the movement.

Edit 1: The move does not always stick so you might have to try a couple of times.

Answer (score 3):

You manage the local destination of each remote repository you clone at the moment of cloning.

As soon as you click the `Clone in Desktop` button on a repository's page (on github.com), GitHub for Mac should open up (assuming you've configured the app to be opened up when `Clone in Desktop` is clicked). When the app opens it first prompts you to choose the location for cloning the repo (cloning means downloading or copying the files). **This prompt is where you set the default location for this particular repository on your local machine.**

Comment: While this is true, I needed to change the location after the fact without reinstalling the app.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious (new Mac user), but the dialog shown by GitHub for Mac includes a field "Where:" but it only shows a list with "Remote Disc", 5 "Favorites" and 3 "Recent places", and no browse button or any way I can see to enter the desired location.

Comment: OK, in continuation of my previous comment, one way of doing it is to use Finder and drag-and-drop the directory to the Favorites list in the left sidebar. Then the directory name does show up in the GitHub for Mac list shown for "Where:".

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of users who came here with the same doubt, let me post also my experience.

I wanted to move the GitHub local folders away from the "Documents" folder to free up iCloud space, and because I really didn't need yet another copy of the codes in addition to the one in my machine and in the GitHub servers. That is how I landed in this page in the first place. So I simply moved the folders to a local folder that is not synchronised with iCloud and when I opened GitHub Desktop to confirm if things were working, the app told me "Couldn't local [repository X]." They had a "Locate..." button, which I used to let the app know where the new location was. And I did this for all of my locally cloned repos. That's it, works like a charm now. If you have a lot of repos cloned locally, it might be a one-time hassle to do this, but there's no further action.